# First data payment gateway integration soap fault error

Tags: php, soap, payment-gateway, hmac, firstdata

Hi I am trying to integrate First data payment gateway integration in soap request method using php. I have downloaded the working sample code from first data but when i am trying to submit a payment with the sample code they gave it is throwing me an error.

The entire php code is

```
<?php


class SoapClientHMAC extends SoapClient {
  public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = NULL) {
    global $context;
    $hmackey = "***********************"; // <-- Insert your HMAC key here
    $keyid = "*****"; // <-- Insert the Key ID here
    $hashtime = date("c");
    $hashstr = "POST\ntext/xml; charset=utf-8\n" . sha1($request) . "\n" . $hashtime . "\n" . parse_url($location,PHP_URL_PATH);
    $authstr = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1",$hashstr,$hmackey,TRUE));
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.11') == -1) {
        ini_set("user_agent", "PHP-SOAP/" . PHP_VERSION . "\r\nAuthorization: GGE4_API " . $keyid . ":" . $authstr . "\r\nx-gge4-date: " . $hashtime . "\r\nx-gge4-content-sha1: " . sha1($request));
    } else {
        stream_context_set_option($context,array("http" => array("header" => "authorization: GGE4_API " . $keyid . ":" . $authstr . "\r\nx-gge4-date: " . $hashtime . "\r\nx-gge4-content-sha1: " . sha1($request))));
    }
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
  }

  public function SoapClientHMAC($wsdl, $options = NULL) {
    global $context;
    $context = stream_context_create();
    $options['stream_context'] = $context;
    return parent::SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
  }
}

$trxnProperties = array(
  "User_Name"=>"",
  "Secure_AuthResult"=>"",
  "Ecommerce_Flag"=>"",
  "XID"=>"",
  "ExactID"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_ExactID"],                  //Payment Gateway
  "CAVV"=>"",
  "Password"=>"********",                                   //Gateway Password
  "CAVV_Algorithm"=>"",
  "Transaction_Type"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_Transaction_Type"],//Transaction Code I.E. Purchase="00" Pre-Authorization="01" etc.
  "Reference_No"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Reference_No"],
  "Customer_Ref"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Customer_Ref"],
  "Reference_3"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Reference_3"],
  "Client_IP"=>"",                                      //This value is only used for fraud investigation.
  "Client_Email"=>$_POST["tb_Client_Email"],            //This value is only used for fraud investigation.
  "Language"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_Language"],                //English="en" French="fr"
  "Card_Number"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Card_Number"],           //For Testing, Use Test#s VISA="4111111111111111" MasterCard="5500000000000004" etc.
  "Expiry_Date"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Month"] . $_POST["ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Year"],//This value should be in the format MM/YY.
  "CardHoldersName"=>$_POST["tbPOS_CardHoldersName"],
  "Track1"=>"",
  "Track2"=>"",
  "Authorization_Num"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Authorization_Num"],
  "Transaction_Tag"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Transaction_Tag"],
  "DollarAmount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_DollarAmount"],
  "VerificationStr1"=>$_POST["tbPOS_VerificationStr1"],
  "VerificationStr2"=>"",
  "CVD_Presence_Ind"=>"",
  "Secure_AuthRequired"=>"",
  "Currency"=>"",
  "PartialRedemption"=>"",

  // Level 2 fields 
  "ZipCode"=>$_POST["tbPOS_ZipCode"],
  "Tax1Amount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax1Amount"],
  "Tax1Number"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax1Number"],
  "Tax2Amount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax2Amount"],
  "Tax2Number"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax2Number"],

  //"SurchargeAmount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_SurchargeAmount"], //Used for debit transactions only
  //"PAN"=>$_POST["tbPOS_PAN"]                          //Used for debit transactions only
  );


$client = new SoapClientHMAC("https://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v12/wsdl");
$trxnResult = $client->SendAndCommit($trxnProperties);


if(@$client->fault){
    // there was a fault, inform
    print "<B>FAULT:  Code: {$client->faultcode} <BR />";
    print "String: {$client->faultstring} </B>";
    $trxnResult["CTR"] = "There was an error while processing. No TRANSACTION DATA IN CTR!";
}
//Uncomment the following commented code to display the full results.

echo "<H3><U>Transaction Properties BEFORE Processing</U></H3>";
echo "<TABLE border='0'>\n";
echo " <TR><TD><B>Property</B></TD><TD><B>Value</B></TD></TR>\n";
foreach($trxnProperties as $key=>$value){
    echo " <TR><TD>$key</TD><TD>:$value</TD></TR>\n";
}
echo "</TABLE>\n";

echo "<H3><U>Transaction Properties AFTER Processing</U></H3>";
echo "<TABLE border='0'>\n";
echo " <TR><TD><B>Property</B></TD><TD><B>Value</B></TD></TR>\n";
foreach($trxnResult as $key=>$value){
    $value = nl2br($value);
    echo " <TR><TD valign='top'>$key</TD><TD>:$value</TD></TR>\n";
}
echo "</TABLE>\n";


// kill object
unset($client);
?>
```

When i submit the payment my page comes to this particular code and the error it throws is

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] in C:\wamp\www\Fd\php\process.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\Fd\php\process.php(49): SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://api.dem...', 'http://secure2....', 1, 0) #1 [internal function]: SoapClientHMAC->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://api.dem...', 'http://secure2....', 1, 0) #2 C:\wamp\www\Fd\php\process.php(104): SoapClient->__call('SendAndCommit', Array) #3 C:\wamp\www\Fd\php\process.php(104): SoapClientHMAC->SendAndCommit(Array) #4 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\Fd\php\process.php on line 48.
```

And the line 48 is

```
return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
```

I couldn't really figure out what this error is. Googled and tried various solutions but no success.Also I have both the soap and openssl enabled in my php server if that is of any help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little bit too late but anyways... just dump that garbage SOAP code, heres my early stage JSON and CURL version

```
<?php

class FirstData
{
        protected $host = "api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com";
        protected $protocol = "https://";
        protected $uri = "/transaction/v12";

        /*Modify this acording to your firstdata api stuff*/
        protected $hmackey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        protected $keyid = "XXXXX";
        protected $gatewayid = "XX000-00";
        protected $password = "XXXXXXX";


        public function request()
        {
                $location = $this->protocol . $this->host . $this->uri;
                $request = array(
                        'transaction_type' => "00",
                        'amount' => 10.00,
                        'cc_expiry' => "0415",
                        'cc_number' => '4111111111111111',
                        'cardholder_name' => 'Test',
                        'reference_no' => '23',
                        'customer_ref' => '11',
                        'reference_3' => '234',
                        'gateway_id' => $this->gatewayid,
                        'password' => $this->password,
                );

                $content = json_encode($request);

                var_dump($content);

                $gge4Date = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", time()) . 'Z';
                $contentType = "application/json";
                $contentDigest = sha1($content);
                $contentSize = sizeof($content);
                $method = "POST";

                $hashstr = "$method\n$contentType\n$contentDigest\n$gge4Date\n$this->uri";

                $authstr = 'GGE4_API ' . $this->keyid . ':' . base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $hashstr, $this->hmackey, true));


                $headers = array( 
                        "Content-Type: $contentType",
                        "X-GGe4-Content-SHA1: $contentDigest",
                        "X-GGe4-Date: $gge4Date",
                        "Authorization: $authstr",
                        "Accept: $contentType"
                );

                //Print the headers we area sending
                var_dump($headers);


                //CURL stuff
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $location);

                //Warning ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                /*Hardcoded for easier implementation, DO NOT USE THIS ON PRODUCTION!!*/
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                //Warning ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

                //This guy does the job
                $output = curl_exec($ch);

                //echo curl_error($ch); 
                $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
                $header = $this->parseHeader(substr($output, 0, $header_size));
                $body = substr($output, $header_size);

                curl_close($ch);
                //Print the response header
                var_dump($header);

                /* If we get any of this X-GGe4-Content-SHA1 X-GGe4-Date Authorization
                 * then the API call is valid */
                if (isset($header['authorization']))
                {
                        //Ovbiously before we do anything we should validate the hash
                        var_dump(json_decode($body));
                }
                //Otherwise just debug the error response, which is just plain text
                else
                {
                        echo $body;
                }
        }

        private function parseHeader($rawHeader)
        {
                $header = array();

                //http://blog.motane.lu/2009/02/16/exploding-new-lines-in-php/
                $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $rawHeader);

                foreach ($lines as $key => $line)
                {
                        $keyval = explode(': ', $line, 2);

                        if (isset($keyval[0]) && isset($keyval[1]))
                        {
                                $header[strtolower($keyval[0])] = $keyval[1];
                        }
                }

                return $header;
        }
}

$firstdata = new FirstData();

$firstdata->request();
```

Comment: can you please help me telling how to/ where to get the $hmack_key and $key_id please? @KukoBits

Comment: How did you find out the name of all the JSON variables? I could not find the documentation for this anywhere??

Comment: Found out the list of JSON variables here for who it helps! (https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/407571-First-Data-Global-Gateway-e4-Web-Service-API-Reference-Guide#4)

Comment: You find the hmack_key and key_id in the following location.  After you login to your firstData account go to the HOME page (default page), look for TERMINALS, it's a side link on the right, click it, then choose one of the terminals (I had 3 since I was in demo mode, so I just chose retail), then click the API-ACCESS tab, it's one of many tabs that appear.  Key_Id will be very obvious where it is, and you just need to generate the hMac Key.  IGNORE the hmac signature calculator, don't need that since the code above will handle that already for you.  Please upvote if this helped.

Comment: If you want to do TEST transactions use transaction type = 05 (pre-auth only) and send value of $0.00, I do this to validate credit cards.

Comment: Just make sure you don't wrap your variables in quotes. Otherwise, this code (with @dhavald's date fix) works for me.

Comment: This works but needs to be updated with @dhavald's fix

Comment: Can I ask where you found the JSON code? I'm running into the same issue and considering switching to the JSON method.

Comment: Can someone post JSON variable name for **CVV2**.

Comment: JSON format names can be found at the [API Reference Guide](https://support.payeezy.com/hc/en-us/articles/206601408-First-Data-Payeezy-Gateway-Web-Service-API-Reference-Guide#4). CVV2 code should be `cvd_code` in JSON.

Answer (score 5):

I tried SOAP with no success, finally had to switch to JSON.
@KukoBit's answer worked for me. Only problem was the date string which is expected in GMT. I solved it by calculating date as follows:

```
$gge4Date = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", time() - (int) substr(date('O'), 0, 3)*60*60) . 'Z';
```

Hope this helps.

ps. I know this should be a comment, but due to points restrictions, I cannot.

Comment: Use gmdate() instead, which will always return GMT time (regardless of your current timezone). `gmdate('c')`

Answer (score 5):

Just a heads up for those who keep getting 'Unauthorized Request. Bad or missing credentials.' .

MAKE SURE you are NOT using your PRODUCTION credentials for DEMO environment. They will not work. Stop pulling your hair out :)
all you have to do is, goto

https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/21510561-first-data-global-gateway-e4sm-demo-accounts

Signup for a free demo. you will generate your hmac, and get your other data there , just like you do in production.

Comment: Your prediction was same. i was using the production credentials. worked like a charm. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new SoapClientHMAC("https://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v12/wsdl");
```

remove ".demo" => "https://api.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v12/wsdl"

You use live access in api first data